# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')

Tags: discord.js, bots

I have an error
CODE:

```js
const prefix = '-';

import fs from 'fs'
 
client.commands = new DiscordJS.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.cjs'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = import(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ + /);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === `test`){
        client.commands.get('test').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

My test.cjs CODE:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    description: "This is a test",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('Test is working');
    }
}
```

Does any1 know how to help??
The Console Error Message is

If any1 can help that would be amazing!
Have a good day!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6mOV.png

Comment: `client.commands.get('test')` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

`.cjs` is CommonJS file, but your code can run on JavaScript.
Try changing your extension to `.js`.